# Looping through JObject nested array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I can not figure out exactly how to did through this JObject in order to retrieve the id property under runs.

I have this following code which will successfully give me the id property that is under entries, but how can I nest this again to go into the runs sections and get those ID's?

JSON:

```
{
  "id": 168,
  "name": "section 1",
  "entries": [
    {
      "id": "908-9876-908",
      "suite_id": 15,
      "name": "List 1",
      "runs": [
        {
          "id": 169,
          "suite_id": 15
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "998-4344-439",
      "suite_id": 16,
      "name": "List 2",
      "runs": [
        {
          "id": 170,
          "suite_id": 16
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

C# Code:

```
JObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(response);

foreach (JObject id in obj["entries"])
{
    string returnable = (string)id["id"];
    Console.WriteLine(returnable);
}
```

I have tried looking at ["entries"]["runs"] but that also was not working.

The print out of this is:

```
908-9876-908
998-4344-439
```

What I would like is

```
169
170
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it using the following code

```cs
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);

foreach (var entry in jsonObject["entries"])
{
    foreach (var run in entry["runs"])
    {
        string returnable = (string)run["id"];
        Console.WriteLine(returnable);
    }               
}
```

You would like to see

```
169
170
```

They are an `id` values from `runs` array, therefore you should enumerate them in the inner loop. You've also missed a comma after `"name": "section 1"`

Comment: Oh man this worked perfectly - I tried something just like this and was getting errors, I must have just been a little off. Thank you so much, hope this post helps someone else

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens_1.htm) to query for nested data inside a `JToken` hierarchy.  It provides support for [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) queries including wildcards `[*]` for arrays:

```
var ids = obj.SelectTokens("entries[*].runs[*].id").Select(i => (long)i).ToList();
```

See: [Querying JSON with complex JSON Path](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ld5BaB).